# Book about teenage clones who end up in a compound somewhere?

Tags: story-identification, books, clones

Girl and a boy - both find out they're clones. She believes she is 'fat', he is described as having olive skin. Turns out his dad is behind it all... (I think the dad dies at the end?) There's a woman called Tessa or something. They are taken to some kind of compound. It's a teen book.

Comment: Welcome to Science Fiction & Fantasy! This question would be improved by going through the checklists here; [How to ask a good story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question)